# Removing consecutive occurrences from end of list python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
ar = np.array([True, False, True, True, True])
```

If the last element is True, I want to remove all of the consecutive true elements at the end of the array. So for example

```
magic_func(ar) => [True, False]
```

If `ar = [True, False, True, False, True]`. Then

```
magic_func(ar) => [True, False, True, False]
```

If `ar = [True, False, False]`, the function does nothing, because the last element is False

Is there a one liner in python to do this? using a numpy library or something

Comment: If `ar = np.array([True, True)` should the function return `np.array([], dtype=bool)`?

Comment: correct the function should return an empty array

Answer (score 1):

This one line function should work, but looks very nasty and probably not efficient lol. Basically the idea is to find the most right `False` and return all values before `False`

```
def magic_func(a):
    return a[:len(a)-np.where(a[::-1]==False)[0][0]] if np.where(a[::-1]==False)[0].size>0 else a[:0]

>>> a = np.array([False, True, True, True, True])
>>> magic_func(a)
array([False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: This is very inefficient: `where()` loops through the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little too magic for my liking, but it does seem to work nicely:

```
>>> ar = np.array([True, False, True, True, True])
>>> ar[np.bitwise_or.accumulate(~ar[::-1])[::-1]]
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

To understand what's going on, first we negate the array, turning the `True`s into `False`s and viceversa, then we reverse the order, then we accumulate the result of OR-ing the array: this will be `False` until the first `True`, and will remain `True` thereafter. reversing this array, we have a boolean indexing array that will get rid of all trailing `True`s.

Comment: This is unnecessarily inefficient: there is no need to go through all the elements of the array.

Comment: And yet it runs twice as fast as your "efficient" solution for the OPs example... You might as well go ahead and downvote and call "unnecessarily inefficient" 80% of all answers to numpy question, as this type of "inefficiencies" are the bread and butter of vectorization.

Comment: I took the example in the question as a toy example. The real question is what the real use case is. For example, for `ar = np.full(1000000, True, dtype=bool); ar[-10] = False`, your solution is 50 (not 2!) times slower than mine. I should have made clear that I did assume that (1) the function would be used with longer arrays than in the example and (2) that very long sequences of True at the end were unlikely. I removed my downvote because your solution is fast when the final array is small, and this is not strictly precluded by the question.

Comment: I added another Numpy based solution that saves time twice: first when looking for the cut limit (no need to go through all the elements) and then when creating the final array (by using the fact that we only need a slice, not a general boolean selection). My pure-Numpy solution is twice as fast as this one, as a consequence (for two best & worst cases).

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.dropwhile` and `np.fromiter` like this.

```
from itertools import dropwhile
np.fromiter(dropwhile(lambda x: x, ar[::-1]), dtype=bool)[::-1]
```

**Edit**

This is more faster way.(Just use `itertools.takewhile`)

```
from itertools import takewhile
ar[:-sum(1 for i in takewhile(lambda x: x, reversed(ar)))]
```

Time:

```
ar = np.array([True, False, True, True, True])

#mine
%timeit ar[:-sum(1 for i in takewhile(lambda x: x, reversed(ar)))]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.84 us per loop

#mine
%timeit np.fromiter(dropwhile(lambda x: x, ar[::-1]), dtype=bool)[::-1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.93 us per loop

#@Jaime
%timeit ar[np.bitwise_or.accumulate(~ar[::-1])[::-1]]
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.63 us per loop

#@askewchan
%timeit ar[:len(ar)-np.argmin(ar[::-1])]
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.24 us per loop

#@xbb
%timeit ar[:len(ar)-np.where(ar[::-1]==False)[0][0]] if np.where(ar[::-1]==False)[0].size>0 else ar[:0]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.61 us per loop
```

PS:

This is no-magic function.

```
def no_magic_func(ar):
    for i in xrange(ar.size-1, -1, -1):
        if not ar[i]:
            return ar[:i+1]
    return ar[0:0]
```

Time:

```
ar = np.array([True, False, True, True, True])

%timeit no_magic_func(ar)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 954 ns per loop
```

Comment: This rebuilds the array element by element, which is quite inefficient.

Comment: @EOL: Yes but, how about this? `np.fromiter(dropwhile(lambda x: x, reversed(ar)), dtype=bool)[::-1]`

Comment: The problem is the same: `fromiter()` builds the result array element by element: this is way less efficient than slicing the original array: `ar[:…]`. (Slicing the original array is currently done in two of the solutions.)

Comment: @EOL: OK...I understand it. Now I've found faster way... `ar[:-sum(1 for i in takewhile(lambda x: x, reversed(ar)))]`

Comment: Good idea. Maybe it is possible to beat the summation: I'd be curious to see how fast is my (askewchan's really) `numpy.argmin()` solution (`argmin()` is essentially a different way of calculating the sum, but without additions).

Comment: The `takewhile` solution currently fails when the array is `[True, True,…, True, False]`: it should return the whole array but returns an empty result instead. A solution is to use `len(ar)-sum(…)`.

Comment: Also note that these timings are for the specific (toy?) examples from the question. The fastest case here is `takewhile()`… which is actually 150 times slower than my solution (very similar to askewhcan's) on `ar = np.full(1000000, True, dtype=bool)`. This is likely due to the fact that `sum(… takewhile(…)… )` loops through elements without NumPy, handles an iterator, and performs many general Python integer sum.

Comment: @EOL: Ah I didn't know the length of the array is such a big matter. As you said, `takewhile` solution become slower if last consecutive `True` become larger. In your 1000000 elements example, if the length of the last consecutive `True` is larger than 10000(1%), numpy solution is faster. So I think, pure numpy solution is generally faster than non-pure numpy solution(In your example case, it's about 100x faster in my environment). Thanks to telling me.:)

Answer (score 1):

It is not so easy to write an time-efficient one-liner, but here is code based on a deleted answer by askewchan:

```
argmin = ar[::-1].argmin()
result = np.array([], dtype=bool) if ar[argmin] else ar[:len(ar)-argmin]
```

This is **more than twice as fast** as Jaime's Numpy-based solution, for `ar = np.full(1000000, True, dtype=bool)` and then either:

- `ar[-10] = False`,
- or `ar[10] = False`

(which are two situations representative of the best and worst cases). However, like in Jaime's solution, finding where the last `False` makes NumPy (1.8.1) go through the *whole* array, which is inefficient. In principle, however, Numpy does not have to do this with `argmin()`, since it could stop at the first `False` encountered.

This looks to me like the solution that uses *the best of Numpy* for *performing the cut* that gives the final array. In principle, NumPy could also be very efficient for finding the cut position.

Comment: But, but... This solution is unnecessarily inefficient! ;-) And yet, it is probably the best that can be done, which kind of proves my point, +1.

Comment: Thank you for your magnanimity. I do agree that with the current implementation of `argmin()`, finding the last `False` in the array is inefficient. I guess that it does not have to be, though, which would make this solution efficient (no time wasted doing unnecessary operations): I opened a NumPy issue on this (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4659).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: updated implementation to deal with a lack of .pop() in numpy arrays

```
def chop_array(ar, condition):
    i = len(ar)
    while (ar[i - 1] == condition and i > 0):
        i = i - 1
    return ar[0:i]

chop_array([True, False, True, False, True], True)
```

Comment: This is a numpy array, which has no `pop` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an almost one-liner (one line for the case where the result is not empty), which should be quite fast (only the necessary elements are looked at):

```
def magic_func(arr):
    try:       
        # The first element starting from the end which differs from the last one sets the limit:
        return arr[:next(index for index in xrange(len(arr)-1, -1, -1) if arr[index] == False)+1]
    except StopIteration:
        return numpy.empty_like(arr)
```

The `next()` simply returns the index of the first element which is `False`. The `+1` at the end is for including it in the result. The `StopIteration` is for the case where all the elements are True.

A **true one-liner** that's a little slower (additional test on the index which yields true is all the elements not `False`) is:

```
ar[:next(index for index in xrange(len(ar)-1, -2, -1) if index == -1 or ar[index] == False)+1]
```

It is relatively legible: the index of the potential last element is scanned, from the end to the beginning, and we stop if either no False was found or as soon as one was found.

Note that this solution has the disadvantage of looping through the original array without using Numpy (this is not good if the array has many True values at the end). It has a couple of advantages over many other solutions:

- **The only elements that are scanned are the necessary ones** (no need to look before the first `False` found)—but, again, this is done with a slower (non-Numpy) method.
- The result is obtained with a **Numpy slicing**, which is **fast**.

As a consequence, this solution is **very fast** when the number of True values at the end of the array is small.